# I use python 3.6 and i want to make sentiment analysis but i have an error in nltk.metrics package?

Tags: python, nltk, precision, metrics, sentiment-analysis

i write the code as here :

```
    print ('pos precision:', nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['pos'], 
    testsets['pos']))
    print ('pos recall:', nltk.metrics.recall(refsets['pos'], 
    testsets['pos']))
```

and the output as here :

```
   line 35, in evaluate_classifier
   print ('pos precision:', nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['pos'], 
   testsets['pos']))
   AttributeError: module 'nltk.translate.metrics' has no attribute 
  'precision'
```

How can i solve this error ?

Comment: Is the code modified from somewhere else? May I know where did you get the code to use `nltk.metrics.precision`? That'll help us clear up the documentation so that other users won't get the same problem. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No big deal, just not calling the correct method.

Try: `nltk.metrics.scores.precision(reference, test)`

http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.metrics.html

ctrl+f for "precision" will get you to documentation

Corrected code:

`print('pos precision:', nltk.metrics.scores.precision(refsets['pos'],testsets['pos']))
print('pos recall:', nltk.metrics.scores.recall(refsets['pos'],testsets['pos']))`

Comment: this error occurred:
  AttributeError: module 'nltk.translate.metrics' has no attribute 'scores'

Comment: nltk.translate is an entirely different module. http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.translate.html?highlight=translate#module-nltk.translate It does not have the .scores method. Seems like you are wanting to do some preprocessing before you get your sentiment scores using the .metrics module. I would need to know more about what you are trying to accomplish. Feel free to ask a new question with more code and what you are trying to do. Happy to help. If the answer above solved the initial problem, please accept as answer.

Comment: https://streamhacker.com/2010/06/16/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-eliminate-low-information-features/     here is the code i use .

Comment: Sorry. but nowhere on that page is there a nltk.translate call. Something else is going on with your code. Instead of using nltk.translate.metrics, can you use nltk.metrics.scores.precision as in the suggested answer? Because nltk.translate does not have the .metrics function.

Comment: Also, that sample code is from 2010. NLTK has had some version changes since then. I'd look at the documentation of the version you are currently using

Comment: yes i use nltk.metrics.scores.precision  but it doesn't work and give me this error     print 'pos precision:', nltk.metrics.scores.precision (refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'scores'

Comment: No problem. To help further I need to know version of NLTK and version of Python (2 or 3)

Comment: The nltk version is 3.2.5.

Comment: now i try it on version 2 , and the same error happen on version 3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398282/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-scores

Comment: The above link should get you there. nltk is packaged kinda weird. basically, just import precision and recall directly ```from nltk import precision``` and ```from nltk import recal```

Comment: it work correctly when i import it , thank you .. but there is another error :(     word_fd.inc(word.lower())
AttributeError: 'FreqDist' object has no attribute 'inc'

Comment: completely different issue. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827058/attributeerror-freqdist-object-has-no-attribute-inc I would make a different question with a sample of your code and error traceback if you get stuck again

Comment: it completely work , thank you so much ..

Comment: Np. happy to help :)